# How to find out direction PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I want to find out the direction from the 2 points from postGIS database. Please see the attached image. I want to find out the direction from the mainPt to any point. But want to get the result as NW, NE, SE or SW. Simply if I get the degree of the angle it can easily be solved.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use ST_Azimuth for that : http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html

This will give you an angle in radians and the 0 rad angle stands for a point in the north of your main point

Comment: Angle is computed clockwise from down-to-up: on the clock: 12=0; 3=PI/2; 6=PI; 9=3PI/2

Comment: SELECT  ST_Azimuth(ST_Point(90.420408,23.788879), ST_Point(90.419745,23.79009))/(2*pi())*360 as degAz; returning 331.300114079087. But from the Map I am observing that the second point is located NW from the first point. How can I understand the direction?

Comment: According to your example : (0-90°)>NE ; (90-180°)>SE ; (180-270°)>SW ; (270-360°)>NW

Comment: I want to put range (0-90) for northeast and (90-180) southeast and (180 - 270) as southwest and (270-360) as northwest .... from postgres using degA_B and degB_A column .. with condition statement can you plz help me to write with these conditions...................select "degA_B", "degB_A", CASE WHEN "degA_B" > CAST (0 AS character) THEN 'northeast' WHEN "degA_B" > CAST (90 AS character) THEN 'southeast' WHEN "degA_B" > CAST (180 AS character) THEN 'southwest' WHEN "degA_B" > CAST (270 AS character) THEN 'northwest' ELSE 'others' END AS directiontext FROM directions;

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in this link https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCardinalDirection

Which convert the ST_Azimuth output into cardinal directions. The function is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_CardinalDirection(azimuth float8) RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$SELECT CASE
  WHEN $1 < 0.0 THEN 'less than 0'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 22.5 THEN 'N'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 67.5 THEN 'NE'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 112.5 THEN 'E'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 157.5 THEN 'SE'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 202.5 THEN 'S'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 247.5 THEN 'SW'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 292.5 THEN 'W'
  WHEN degrees($1) < 337.5 THEN 'NW'
  WHEN degrees($1) <= 360.0 THEN 'N'
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE COST 100;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION ST_CardinalDirection(float8) IS 'input azimuth in radians; returns N, NW, W, SW, S, SE, E, or NE';
```

To use the function, same link has the example as follows

```
SELECT
  degrees(ST_Azimuth(origin, pt)) AS azimuth_in_degrees,
  ST_CardinalDirection(ST_Azimuth(origin, pt))
FROM (
  SELECT
    'POINT(0 0)'::geometry AS origin,
    ST_MakePoint(cos(radians(x)), sin(radians(x))) AS pt
  FROM generate_series(0, 365, 15) AS x
) AS f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the degrees like following (see the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html) example):

```
SELECT degrees(ST_Azimuth(ST_Point(25, 45), ST_Point(75, 100))) AS deg;
```

Comment: I want to put range (0-90) for northeast and (90-180) southeast and (180 - 270) as southwest and  (270-360) as northwest .... from postgres using degA_B and degB_A column .. with condition statement  can you plz help me to write with these conditions...................select "degA_B", "degB_A", CASE WHEN "degA_B"  > CAST (0 AS character) THEN 'northeast' 
WHEN "degA_B"  > CAST (90 AS character) THEN 'southeast' 
WHEN "degA_B"  > CAST (180 AS character) THEN 'southwest' 
WHEN "degA_B"  > CAST (270 AS character) THEN 'northwest' ELSE 'others'
END AS directiontext
FROM directions;

Comment: Ask another question. I will not answer you in a comment... ;-)

Comment: i have crossed the questions limit sir

Comment: dont know how to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

SN = 0-45 && 315-360 , WE =45-135, NS = 135-225, EW = 225 -315.

Use this to find degree:

```
Select degrees(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(st_linemerge(geom)), ST_ENDPOINT(st_linemerge(geom))))
```

I have use this to find road direction travel name postgis