# How to show PostGIS distance in Meter

Tags: postgis-2.0

I have calculate distance from one point to a linestring. I have used the following query

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT geom::geometry AS road_network from linestring)

SELECT  ST_Distance(ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(road_network, ST_Line_Locate_Point(road_network,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(90.402 23.753)'))), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(90.402 23.753)'))  as Dist 


FROM data

ORDER BY Dist
Limit 1
```

Its returning the following result

```
0.000501079237817185
```

I want to get the result in Meter. How can I convert it? I am using WGS84 projection system. I know the `ST_Transform` function but I need a perfect query where I use this function.

Thanks

Comment: For length in meters use "ST_Length_Spheroid" function. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32874/how-to-calculate-length-of-polyline-geometry-for-several-tables-in-postgis

Comment: Thanks but I am newbie. If you can answer with codes it will help me too much.

Comment: Doing is learning. replace ST_DISTANCE with ST_Length_Spheroid and add 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]' to second argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you locating and interpolating those points to get the distance?

About your question: Easiest is to convert to geogrphy type on the fly:

```
SELECT  ST_Distance(geom::geography,ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(90.402 23.753)')) as Dist 
FROM linestring
ORDER BY Dist
Limit 1;
```

Comment: I am trying to query closest roads from a point. This is why I used locate and interpolate. Could you please make my code to convert into Meter? It will be a great help. Thanks for reply

Comment: @DevilsDream Have you tried the above. It will give you the distance to the closest road in the table linestring (which from your query seems to be the name of your linestring table). You can yourself cast geometry to geograpy like I did (::geography) if you absolutely want to make it complicated. distance calculations on geography type returns in meter.

Comment: Thats like a boss. Thanks a lot Nicklas Aven. Could you please check this issue http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54427/how-to-findout-direction-postgis